# How to get PII Entities for non-text field in Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I've created a Azure search Blob Index whose model looks somewhat like the below JSON on search

```
"value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "metadata_storage_content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "masked_text": null,
            "language": "en",
            "content": {
                "botName": "*****",
                "date": "*****",
                "channel": "******",
                "userid": "******",
                "conversationid": "*******",
                "isConversationIncomplete": false,
                "location": "",
                "locale": "",
                "messages": [ {
                        "date": "*****",
                        "isfromuser": "true",
                        "message": "Hi",
                        "sentiment": "positive",
                        "intent": "***** Intent",
                        "isConversationIncomplete": "false",
                        "id": "***"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "****",
                        "isfromuser": "true",
                        "message": "My number is 999******",
                        "sentiment": "positive",
                        "intent": "***** Intent",
                        "isConversationIncomplete": "false",
                        "id": "****"
                    }]
            },
            "pii_entities": []
        }
```

I also want to create a PII detection skill for each message in the messages array, you can see the skill config in the image below

[image]

the problem is that I'm not able to change the Input value to any property from the result entity, it allows only the values as "languageCode" or "text" how can I create the PII skill for a input of my choice?

Comment: Entities in text include: phone number, email address, mailing address, passport number. What kind of input are you working with ?

Comment: might be any, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

[PII Detection cognitive skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-pii-detection) uses the detection models provided in Azure Cognitive Services for Language which only accept text as type. If you would like to check any other properties that have a different type, you could use a [custom skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api) and convert your property type to text and then send this as PII Detection skill input.